# The name SpaceProcessingModeValues does not exist in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, space

In my ASP.net program i have a class to open a word document, find a boormark and insert a given text

The error i get is: the name SpaceProcessingModeValues does not exist in the current context.

```cs
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(strFileName, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
        IEnumerable<BookmarkStart> res = from bm in      mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
            where bm.Name == "strField"
            select bm;
        int x = 0;

        BookmarkStart bookmark = res.SingleOrDefault();
        if (bookmark != null)
        {
            OpenXmlElement parent = bookmark.Parent; // bookmark's parent element

            var paragraph1 = new Paragraph {RsidParagraphAddition = "00023529", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "003E1BA6"};

            var run1 = new Run();
            var text1 = new Text("Text : "){ Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };

            run1.Append(text1);
            var bookmarkStart1 = new BookmarkStart {Name = "_GoBack", Id = 0};
            var bookmarkEnd1 = new BookmarkEnd {Id = 0};

            var run2 = new Run();
            var text2 = new Text();
            text2.Text = strGivenText;

            run2.Append(text2);

            paragraph1.Append(run1);
            paragraph1.Append(bookmarkStart1);
            paragraph1.Append(bookmarkEnd1);
            paragraph1.Append(run2);

            parent.InsertBeforeSelf(paragraph1);
        }

        // close saves all parts and closes the document
        mainPart.Document.Save();
        document.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: I just found out what i did wrong. From Nuget i took the DocumentFormat.OpenXml SDK instead of the OpenXml SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the references  DocumentFormat.OpenXml namespace

Comment: SpaceProcessingModeValues is an Enum

Comment: if you dont find this than you need to download-- Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office here is the link----http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124